# My div children are not contained in the parent div

Tags: html, css

Here is my code, I am trying to align the children divs beside each other with 50% width. However it's not working, what am I missing?

```css
.container{ 
  width: 900px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.child{
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to keep using floats as I am trying to mimic an HTML generated by another system.

Comment: I'd like to keep using floats as I am trying to mimic an HTML generated by another system.

Comment: You are also missing a **clearfix**.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am new to CSS this will help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#1. This solution with `box-sizing: border-box` for `.child` (most likely this is what you need):

```css
.container{ 
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.child{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
</div>
```

#2. This solution with `flexbox`:

```css
.container{ 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.child{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /*float: left;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
</div>
```

#3. This solution with `grid`:

```css
.container{ 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.child{
  width: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /*float: left;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this

```css
.container{ 
  width: 900px;
  background: red;
  display: inline
}
.child{
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  float:left
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello hello hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like to keep using floats as I am trying to mimic an HTML generated by another system.

Comment: I updated again

Comment: Thanks! but why display inline? is it recommended for divs?

Comment: Displays an element as an inline element (like <span>). Any height and width properties will have no effect

Comment: but this way, the parent div doesn't have any borders..

Comment: If you are going to use borders " width: calc(50%- 4px);"

Answer (score 1):

The reason (width 50% doesnt work) is that you add the border 2px to the div. Then the width of div will be 50% + 4px (2px left, 2px right) so there is not enough space to include two div in the same line.

Therefore here is the solution

```
.child{
 width: calc(50% - 4px);
}
```

Or this, if the child doesnt need to resize

```
.child{
 width: 446px; /*(900/2)-4*/
}
```

Comment: i edit already =]

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the `box-sizing` property. As you are using border, you need to set the value to `border-box;`. It is a good practice to set this property globally like :

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Comment: I'd like to keep using floats as I am trying to mimic an HTML generated by another system.

Comment: Updated the answer